# jenkins - how to view external job's log directory?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to use jenkins to monitor an external job. One of the optional inputs to the external job is path to a temporary log directory lets (say, the log directory is `/tmp/testlog-UUID`), where the logs of the tests are written.

Once the job is complete, what approaches can I use to have this directory / folder available via browser, so that everyone can see the test results (and logs) from the browser rather than logging into the host and reading files from `/tmp/testlog-UUID`.

Say, something like this: `http://<server>/job/testlog-UUID`

Also, posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/o0PMScDqllE

Comment: Did you consider redirecting the output to the build directory?  Then it would be available in the standard GUI.

Comment: where is the build directory located ? thanks

Comment: If you run a shell script, that directory will be your build directory, but I think I misinterpreted your question, and it appears you've gotten an answer straight from the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external job monitoring feature currently (as of 1.510) only supports sending a single stream of data (aka "console output") and nothing else. There are all sorts of obvious improvements that we should be making, including this, but no one seems to have enough cycles to do it, which is a shame.

The current work around is to put everything into this single "console output", but you probably know that already.